# JQuery Performance: removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I have JS that runs to remove a class "modified" from all descendants of a form element. Which will perform better?

```
$form.find('*').removeClass('modified');
```

or

```
$form.find('.modified').removeClass('modified');
```

Or is there an even better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it yourself https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Why would you query all elements when you are only interested in that class in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl, maybe all the elements have that class :P

Comment: @op then please post the result here! edit: oh someone already did..

Comment: How many elements do you have in your form?  If it's less than 2000, you won't notice the difference.  If it's more than 2000, you have a problem with your form!  ie other than for pure educational reasons, don't micro-optimise things that don't need it.

Comment: @freedomn-m You're right, but I still wouldn't advise someone to use the first method OP asked about. Searching through the whole form with `*` is really not the way to go.

Comment: @freedomn-m My interest is somewhat educational. For all its methods JQuery generally performs an internal check on each element to see if whatever action really needs performed. Was wondering if making it check twice through css selection was worthwhile. From accepted answer sounds like it is!

Comment: Always worth mentioning/checking if for educational reasons.   While the second option would be the one a real-world developer would use, as the selector becomes more complicated, it takes "longer" (order of ms) to find the elements and, in those cases, it may be worth a blanket update.  ie performance also depends on the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way ( `.find('.modified')` ) is better, performance-wise, across all major desktop browsers (Opera, IE, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Chromium, didn't test mobile browsers).

**Google Chrome 61**: 22K operation/s vs 214K operation/s.
**Firefox  55**: 26K op/s vs 342K op/s.
**Chromium 59**: 21K op/s vs 184K op/s.
**Opera 46.0**: 22K op/s vs 198K op/s.
**Edge 25.10586.672**: 5K op/s vs 64K op/s.
**IE 11.962.10586**:  6K op/s vs 117K op/s.

May vary through browsers.

Here is the test setup:
https://jsperf.com/jquery-remove-classes/1

Comment: If it may vary through browsers, I'm not sure you really want to state that one way *is* better so objectively.

Comment: @BoltClock I edited my answer to specify that across all major desktop browsers, the function which is not searching through all the form content is better everytime.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for performance, I'd try to use native JavaScript. The following script should execute extremely fast, but to be honest I don't have the time to measure performance right now. Anyway, here is a vanilla JS version:

```js
var form_elem = document.getElementById('form');
var elements = form_elem.getElementsByClassName('modified');

while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].classList.remove('modified');
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
<span class="modified">1</span>
<span class="modified">2</span>
<span class="modified">3</span>
<span class="modified">4</span>
<span class="modified">5</span>
<span class="modified">6</span>
<span class="modified">7</span>
<span class="modified">
    <span class="modified">
        <span class="modified">9</span>
    </span>
</span>
</form>
```

Comment: This is obviously the best solution OP, if you're looking for performance. This method should always be 8-10 times faster than the best libraries (I added it to [the benchmark](https://jsperf.com/jquery-remove-classes/1) ).

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Nothing beats vanilla JS in 99% of the time :-)